# Magento 2 : Image cache issue when update bulk product programmatically

Tags: magento2, product-images, cache

In my case, I have to **update product images** and other data programmatically from API in Magento.

All data is updated after the indexer command but for new images, I have to flush the **product image cache.**

Is there any other solution to get the new image of the product without flushing the image cache

Comment: How you update products , by backend or by manualy run any page ?

Comment: programmatically using API